# SSD not detected when connected via USB disk docking station

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, docking-station, hardware-detection

<sub>(Moving this question from unix.SX)</sub>

I'm connecting a newly-bought SSD (Samsung 850 EVO) to my Linux Mint 18.3 via a USB 3.0-connected disk docking station ([this one](https://plugable.com/products/usb3-sata-u3/)). Unfortunately, the disk does not seem to be usable this way.

`lsusb` yields:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
```

and `lshw -c disk` yields:

```
  *-disk UNCLAIMED        
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: USB3-SATA-U3
       vendor: Plugable
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
       version: 0
       serial: B6250000000000000001
       configuration: ansiversion=6
```

the tail of `dmesg` is:

```
[19688.116910] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19688.116915] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[19688.116918] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[19708.965860] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19708.965865] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[19708.965868] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[19722.865166] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

but `fdisk /dev/sdd` results in:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdd: No such file or directory
```

Is this a problem with the SSD? The docking station? the kernel? My distribution's userland? And - how can get the disk to show up?

Notes:

- The docking station has worked with other disks in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a problem with the docking station?

Yes

> Is this dock compatible with the Samsung 840 & 850 EVO series of SSDs?
>   No, the Samsung 840 & 850 EVO SSDs do not work with the ASM1051E chipset in this docking station. If you have a Samsung 840 or 850 EVO SSD, consider our newer USB3-SATA-UASP1 docking station instead.

The docking station is not compatible with your Samsung 850 EVO.

> how can get the disk to show up?

Use a different docking station.

> The docking station has worked with other disks in the past.

The fact other drives have worked in the past is immaterial to your current problem

[Source](https://plugable.com/products/usb3-sata-u3/)

Comment: That's very weird because other manufacturers who use the same ASM1051E chipset specifically claim it's compatible with the 840 EVO.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Likely a combination of a firmware limitation and a older chipset, resulted in a product refresh, since it was easier from a product engineering perspective.  Author has the 850 EVO, the FAQ could in theory also be poorly written, in the sense it actually only applies to the 859 EVO.  What isn’t in doubt, is the fact the author, needs a different docking station.

Comment: So, +1, but I don't understand how this can be the case if the docking station is SATA-conformant and so is the drive.

Comment: @einpoklum The incompatibility has to do with the USB chipset.  I suspect it's more about the firmware then anything.  Try to update the [firmware](https://plugable.com/drivers/hddockfirmware/),  Additionally, "The 1053E is a newer chipset than the 1051. It uses a bit less power, and generally has better throughput, especially when used with a UASP compliant host controller and OS (i.e; Win 8/8.1). ", is the major difference between the two.

Comment: I could determine the reason the drive is not compatible, likely has to do with the sector size of the drive, given most of the firmware updates specifically call out "Improved support for 512e format".

Comment: This is directed at the revenge downvoter, if you are going to downvote my answer, at least tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...
Same kind of issue here and, no effective root cause.
I use a Konig USB3 docking for SATA drives.
It is connected to a Windows 10 Pro.

The docking is working with any HDD device.
The docking is working with a Kingston A400 (480gb) SSD.
The docking is NOT working with a Samsung 870QVO (1tb) > issue with the device in the devmgmt.msc console.
Same behaviour on another Windows 10 system with this Konig USB3 docking.

The Samsung 870QVO is properly regognized with an older STA to USB2 adapter.
The disk has been initialized with this one and a unique NTFS partition has been defined on it.
Still, after this process it is NOT recognized in the Konig SATA3 docking.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that this is not an appropriate "Answer" on this forum. It is a good question and should be posted as such, perhaps with a link to this question.